# How can i fix error LNK2038 after adding tinyxml2?

Tags: c++, c++17, tinyxml2

I have a project that compiles normally and i need to use tinyxml2 library in it, but when i add it there appears 2 linking errors

```
Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2'
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug'
```

i can't say for sure, but maybe thats msvc-only issue because i never was facing such problem in clang

Comment: Looks like you're linking against the debug library instead of the release one.

Comment: Don't mix debug and release meaning you need to link release libraries to release applications and debug libraries to debug applications.